# How do I unset all key bindings defined in persp-mode-map and persp-key-map?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, persp-mode

I want to unset all key bindings defined in persp-mode-map and persp-key-map.

As usual, I tried the following but the bindings remain effective sticky.
This is a behavior that I have never experienced in other modes unlike persp-mode, because the prefix-command like 'persp-key-map was unused?

```lisp
(eval-after-load "persp-mode-autoloads" '(setq persp-mode-map (make-sparse-keymap)))
(eval-after-load "persp-mode-autoloads" '(setq persp-key-map (make-sparse-keymap)))
```

Even if it's stripped down to

```lisp
(setq persp-mode-map (make-sparse-keymap))
```

After setting both nil to check, the result is the same even at the moment when the variables are nil comfirmed by describe-variable.
Is there any effective method?

Comment: Please say what you mean by "didn't work". Thx.

Have you tried just setting those variables to `nil`?

Comment: Put all such clarification into the question. Comments can be deleted at any time. Thx.

Comment: Fixed the question as you told me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

```lisp
(custom-set-variables
 '(persp-keymap-prefix nil))
```

The persp-keymap-prefix is described as "The prefix for activating the persp-mode keymap.", defined by defcustom.